# Listing contents of SQL table on ASP.NET web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have Windows Server 2012 R2 and SQL Server 2016. There are many events writing to SQL table.

I want to build a  web page to list events those are getting directly from connected SQL Server table.

Both SQL Server and IIS(8.5) are installed on the same machine.

The page would need to be dynamically updated whenever SQL Server table's record added/changed.

I really have no clue where to move on right now. Could anyone briefly explain me steps I need to do or throw me a proper "how to" article PLEASE?

Also, is there a way to performed without doing Visual Studio projects and such. I plan to automate the process with Powershell scripts.

Comment: There are a TON of examples and tutorials out there. Spend 15 minutes on Google and you'll have lots and lots.

Comment: @VDWWD I did. REALLY. I can't figure out the correct formulation of the process.

Comment: Can you write if you are using Webforms o MVC? To automate you can use Powershell or Windows services or, simply, a console application scheduled in "scheduled tasks".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link should help you ...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw738475.aspx